# Set reference in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, super

I want to set a reference with a value, which I calculate in constructor.
Is this possible and how?

```
Class::Class(float data1, float data2, ..) : Superclass(calculatedValue)
{
    float calculatedValue = complex calculated from data1, data2, ...
}
//error, because the compiler doesn't know the calculatedValue in the first line.
```

Thanks for your solutions!

**Edit:**

If I use the answer from @dasblinkenlight I get this exception:

> Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll File: c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector Line:
>   1754
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

Comment: `[e.g. In Java I can easily use super(calculatedValue);]` Are you sure? `super` has to be the first statement in the constructor as far as I remember.

Comment: What's the signature of `Superclass`'s constructor? Is it `Superclass(float)` or `Superclass(float&)`?

Comment: @tkausl I apologize, you're right.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It is Superclass(float&)

Comment: OK, why does the constructor take non-const reference? That complicates things, so you better be sure you need it.

Comment: You seem to want to hand `Superclass` a reference to a local variable. That reference will become dangling and useless soon afterwards. What are you really trying to achieve? Can you show what `Superclass` intends to do with that reference?

Comment: @juanchopanza because the float& changes and if I use a const it couldn't.

Comment: @FreddyC. That makes no sense. What do object do you want that reference to refer to? It can't be the temporary result of a calculation.

Comment: We're going to need a proper [mcve] including an explanation of what you are trying to achieve and why you think storing a reference to an external `float` is the best way to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Superclass` takes `float&`, you must allocate space for the value before providing a reference to superclass. Next, you must set the value to the result of the computation before calling `Superclass` constructor.

You can do it by placing the code to compute `calculatedValue` in a private static member function, and making an instance variable for the `float`:

```
private:
    float val;
    static float calculateValue(float data1, float data2, ...) {
        return complex calculated from data1, data2
    }
public:
    Class::Class(float data1, float data2, ...)
    :   Superclass(val = calculateValue(data1, data2, ...)) {
    }
```

Now `Superclass` can set its reference to `val` of subclass, which in turn is set to the result of calling `calculateValue` member function on the parameters passed to the constructor.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/v591rO)

Comment: OP specifies reference though.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Right, now that he's clear about that, I modified the solution to work with the reference. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Is it legal to assign to `val` before it is formally constructed?

Comment: If I use this answer, I get a Excpetion: vector subscript out of range

Comment: @FreddyC. What vector? Where's the subscript? You need to specify this in your question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ok, I changed my question with full excpetion.

Comment: @FreddyC. That's not what I was looking for, though: there is no `vector` anywhere in your code sample, and there is no subscript operator `[]` used in your code either. That is what's needed to figure out what is going on with that exception that you get.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am sorry, I have made the example code to simple. But now I have it already fixed.